Prove/disprove: For $a, b, c\in \mathbb{Z}$, if $c$ divides $a^2$ and $b^2$, then $c^2$ divides $ab$
I've been given this problem as part of a number theory exercise.
So far I've gotten that there exist integers $q_1, q_2$ such that $a^2 = q_1c, b^2 = q_2c$. Then I tried multiplying to get $ab\cdot ab = q_1q_2c^2$. Here I got stuck - I want to say the $c^2$ must either divide $ab$ or $ab$, thus it divides $ab$ - but this is simply not true, counterexample: $6$ divides $2\cdot9$ but divides neither $2$ nor $9$.
Any help would be appreciated. My knowledge on number theory is very limited, since as I said, this is our first homework assignment. So please use elementary stuff if you answer, thanks.

If $,a!=b,$ then it claims $,c\mid a^2\Rightarrow c^2\mid a^2,,$ with infinitely many obvious counterexamples, e.g. $,c = a^2 > 1.,$ It's always a good idea to first look for simple counterexamples in "(dis)Prove" exercises (please do so before posting such questions here, since usually trivial counterexamples only add noise to the site, e.g. cluttering search results).

You are not able to prove it because it's false. As I mentioned in the comments, a simple counterexample is $c=4, a=2, b=6$.

Now if $c$ was a prime, then it would have been true. That is because $c\mid a^2\Rightarrow c\mid a$ and $c\mid b^2\Rightarrow c\mid b$ implying $c^2\mid ab$.

Great, thanks. I remember that once my professor said that it's very hard to prove a theorem that's false.
